# How can i set JSON data directly into string variable in java?

Tags: android

This is my JSON data, In below code, I have JSON data which stored into String variable. But it cause an error with red curly line in eclipse.

```
String strJson="
        {
            \"Employee\" :[
            {
                \"id\":\"01\",
                \"name\":\"Gopal Varma\",
                \"salary\":\"500000\"
            },
            {
                \"id\":\"02\",
                \"name\":\"Sairamkrishna\",
                \"salary\":\"500000\"
            },
            {
                \"id\":\"03\",
                \"name\":\"Sathish kallakuri\",
                \"salary\":\"600000\"
            }
            ]
        }";
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

The following characters are reserved in Java and must be properly escaped to be used within strings:

- Backspace is replaced with `\b`
- Newline is replaced with `\n`
- Tab is replaced with `\t`
- Carriage return is replaced with `\r`
- Form feed is replaced with `\f`
- Double quote is replaced with `\"`
- Backslash is replaced with `\\`

Therefor your string must escape those characters:

```
//Readable version for demonstration
String strJson = "
                { \\\"Employee\\\" :[ 
                     {  
                          \\\"id\\\":\\\"01\\\", 
                          \\\"name\\\":\\\"Gopal Varma\\\",
                          \\\"salary\\\":\\\"500000\\\" 
                     }, 
                     {
                          \\\"id\\\":\\\"02\\\",
                          \\\"name\\\":\\\"Sairamkrishna\\\",
                          \\\"salary\\\":\\\"500000\\\" 
                     }, 
                     { 
                         \\\"id\\\":\\\"03\\\",
                         \\\"name\\\":\\\"Sathish kallakuri\\\",
                         \\\"salary\\\":\\\"600000\\\" 
                     } 
                     ] 
                }";
```

```
//Compilable version that Java will like
String strJson = "{ \\\"Employee\\\" :[ {  \\\"id\\\":\\\"01\\\", \\\"name\\\":\\\"Gopal Varma\\\", \\\"salary\\\":\\\"500000\\\" }, { \\\"id\\\":\\\"02\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Sairamkrishna\\\",\\\"salary\\\":\\\"500000\\\" }, { \\\"id\\\":\\\"03\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"Sathish kallakuri\\\", \\\"salary\\\":\\\"600000\\\" } ] }";
```

Comment: thank u very much. while i put into single line it's working fine but in the format specification is not working very well.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by '_in the format specification is not working very well_'. Are you trying to parse the JSON? Your question was how to get your variable working, which the code that I have provided has done :)